# How to make Frontend_controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to create frontend_controller extend from My_controller and then extend from CI_controller
as below code

In Configure I created **__autoload** function for calling class name and file

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is for wellcome pages**

```
 class welcome extends Frontend_controler {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

}
```

**This is Frontend_controller**

```
<?php
class Frontend_controler extends My_controler{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

**This is My_controller**

```
<?php
class My_controler extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And the finally I create **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I got only blank pages (white empty pages) when I load my website

What I am wrong with this code?

PLease help thanks advance!!!

Comment: Have you configured `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on index.php to see your errors? that will throw some clues about what is exactly your error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my Froentend_Controller and MY_Controller 
I've change my as bellow so it will work on linux hosting
1, Renamed: file Frontend_controller to : Frontend_Controller
2, Renamed: file Admin_controller    to : Admin_Controller
NOTES: We have to remember that C first character of your file name and your class in your file name have to capital letter as above centanc.
And 
When we Extends for other Controller we have to call keep good format as will

Example:
MY_Controller.php

```
 Class Pages extends Frontend_Controller{
       public function __contruct(){
       parent::__construct();
}
}
```

pages.php {pages controller}

```
 Class Pages extends Frontend_Controller{
       public function __contruct(){
       parent::__construct();
}
}
```

Admin

```
Class Admin extends Admin_Controller{
      public function __contruct(){
           parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: If you named your file and class named is wrong you will get blank pages (empty pages) when you load your site**